Group of Characters of $\text{SL}_{n+1}$
We work over $\mathbb{C}$. Let $G=\text{SL}_{n+1}$ be the algebraic group of matrices with determinant $1$. Let $\text{M}(G)$ be the group of characters of $G$, that is the group of morphisms of algebraic groups $G\to \mathbb{G}_m$.
I have studied that $\text{M}(H)\simeq \mathbb{Z}^n$, where $H$ is the maximal torus of $G$, and looking online it seems that also $\text{M}(B)\simeq \mathbb{Z}^n$, with $B$ a Borel subgroup of $G$.
But what is $\text{M}(G)$? If we consider $\text{Gl}_{n+1}$ I thought the determinant was an example of character, but in this other case I have no clue (not even for the associated group of $1$-parameter subgroups).

It's trivial. ${}$

Der @QiaochuYuan, thank you for answering my question so fast. Do you have a reference in mind, or would you like to expand a bit your comment? Thanks in advance

I'm not sure what the easiest way to prove this from scratch is, but you can show that the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_{n+1}(\mathbb{C})$ has trivial abelianization, or equivalently that it is equal to its own commutator subalgebra. So it does not admit any nonzero homomorphisms to the Lie algebra of $\mathbb{G}m$. $\mathfrak{sl}{n+1}(\mathbb{C})$ is even simple but that's stronger than what's needed here.

You can check that $[\mathrm{SL}{n+1}, \mathrm{SL}{n+1}] = \mathrm{SL}_{n+1}$, and note that any character is trivial on commutators.
